# Issue with positioning the elements at the edges of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to position the these two arrow indicators at the left and right edges of the screen with any size:

```css
.arrow-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 5000;
  z-index: 12;
}

.arrow-container > div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #373639;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0.35rem);
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*padding: 11px 17px 11px 17px;*/
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 6px;
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #100021) drop-shadow(1px 0.01em 1px #0d021a);
  transition: background 200ms, transform 300ms;
}

.arrow-container > div span {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px #100021) drop-shadow(1px 0.01em 1px #0d021a);
  color: red;
  font-size: 5em;
}

#right-arrow, #left-arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

.key-arrow {

}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
            <div id="left-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129168;</span></div>
           <div id="right-arrow" class="key-arrow"><span>&#129170;</span></div>
        </div>
```

As you see they are now positioned at the left corner, this is accepted for the left indicator but the right one should be positioned at the right corner.

I used grid with no success. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modify your display property in the class arrow-container like:

.arrow-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 37%;
      width: 95%;
      display: flex;
      grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-perspective: 5000;
      z-index: 12;
    }
```